# What is the passphrase for opening a BitLocker disk on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, encryption, gnome-disk-utility

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. When opening GNOME Disks, I can see a padlock on the Bitlocker partition. If I click the unlock button, I am prompted for a passphrase.

What passphrase should I enter? Entering the password of my Windows' user does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When prompted for your passphrase, you need to enter your BitLocker recovery key. It looks something like:

```
318846-013959-335082-562221-588214-181456-652498-331848
```

### How to find your BitLocker recovery key:

When you enabled BitLocker full disk encryption on your Windows partition, you were prompted to save a recovery key on an external USB stick, or somewhere else. The file is a text file named something like `BitLocker Recovery Key ....txt`. If you can still log in to Windows, you can create this recovery key again. For more information, see: [Finding your BitLocker recovery key in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6)